# How to convert json file to csv file in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv, data-conversion

I have this json file which contains a list of objects

```
[ {
    "infos": [
      { "localisation": "Kassel" },
      { "date": "01.08.2023" },
      { "places": "1 freier Platz" }
    ],

    "applying email": "exemple@starke.ma",
    "additional infos": { 
       "name": "jhon", 
       "position": "RH", 
       "email": "email@email.com" }
  },
  {
    "infos": [
      { "places": "1 freier Platz" }
    ],
    "applying email": "",
    "applying link": "www.exemple.com",
    "additional infos": {
       "name": "jhon", 
       "position": "RH", 
       "email": "email@email.com"
    }
  },]
```

and I want to convert it into csv file (the object contains other fields but I wanted to make is as simple as possible)  the problem is that the file contains nested objects and some field in the nested objects are missing from other objects in the list as what you can see in the infos fields (in the first item on the list you can see a localisation field under the infos field but it's missing in the second object of the list), what i want to achieve is that my csv file header will contain all the field (the missing ones too) and if it didn't find that missing field in the json object while appending data to it , i want to ignore it and let the place empty

Comment: One issue you have is that a CSV file is generally a flat piece of 2D-structured data whereas JSON is more tree-like in nature and doesn't necessarily "translate" into rows of columns easily. While someone can give you an answer for the specific use-case you describe, it likely can't be universally-applied for all JSON data, so you should be more specific in your question.

Answer (score 1):

My preferred method to save to CSV is with [`DataFrame.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_csv) and pandas also has a [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) method which could have been the shortest way to flatten this, but I'm not quite sure how to handle the `infos` lists.

However, if you parse the JSON into a list of python dictionaries (`pData`)

```py
import json
jData = '''
[ { "infos": [{ "localisation": "Kassel" }, { "date": "01.08.2023" }, { "places": "1 freier Platz" }],
    "applying email": "exemple@starke.ma",
    "additional infos": {"name": "jhon", "position": "RH", "email": "email@email.com" }  },
  { "infos": [{ "places": "1 freier Platz" }],
    "applying email": "", "applying link": "www.exemple.com",
    "additional infos": {"name": "jhon", "position": "RH", "email": "email@email.com"} }] 
''' ## I removed the last comma bc it was causing error when parsing

pData = json.loads(jData)
```

then you can flatten it with this [`flattenObj`](https://pastebin.com/v3Fep60B) function<sup>([view examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzCDa.png))</sup> before converting to pandas DataFrames and the saving as CSV:

```py
import pandas as pd
csv_path = 'x.csv' ## path/name of csv file to save to

# pd.DataFrame([flattenObj(d, kSep=' > ') for d in pData]).to_csv(csv_path, index=False)
df = pd.DataFrame([flattenObj(d, kSep=' > ') for d in pData])
df.to_csv(csv_path, index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python has a module called "csv" that has methods for reading and writing CSV files. You can use the csv.DictReader() method to read a JSON file into a CSV file. The method takes in a JSON object, converts it into a csv file, and returns a reader object that can be used to iterate over the rows of the resulting csv file.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue with a recent project. I used the built in csv module

```
def generate_csv(records):
field_names = [&#39;Ticker&#39;, &#39;Quantity&#39;, &#39;Cost Per Share&#39;,         &quot;Date&quot;]
with open(&#39;positions.csv&#39;, &#39;w&#39;) as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=field_names)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(records)
```

this assumes you already have your data in the format you need, in my case, a list of dictionaries that I pass into the function. It reads through one dictionary at a time placing each record in its corresponding column based on the key names that are defined in field_names.

Im brand new to this so I've probably done this in a terribly inefficient way but it worked for me.